# How can I make VS Code add parentheses when autocompleting functions?

Tags: function, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, parentheses

Is is possible to tweak VS Code so that when function gets autocompleted, it is written with `()` instead of just plain function name?

For example when I type `str` and autocomplete to `strlen` I would like to get `strlen()`, it saves quite some time.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It can be solved by ticking `javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls` property up.

[image]

Comment: Appears not to work for methods -- opened a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676976/vscode-autocomplete-function-and-method-parentheses-javascript

Answer (score 26):

For Python when using the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) the relevant setting is:

`python.autocomplete.addBrackets`

As per the [comment bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533379/vscode-add-parentheses-when-autocompleting-functions#comment122342427_60472880), if you use [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) the setting is:

`python.analysis.completeFunctionParens`

Comment: If you are using Pylance, relevant setting is `python.analysis.completeFunctionParens` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/37)

Answer (score 14):

For C and C++, use this setting:

```
"C_Cpp.autocompleteAddParentheses": true
```

Answer (score 8):

Some language extensions allow using `(` as a so-called ["commit character"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem.commitCharacters) to trigger the insertion of a completion item. This works in at least TypeScript, JavaScript and Haxe.

If `"editor.autoClosingBrackets"` has not been disabled, this will also auto-insert the closing `)`.

[image]

If it doesn't work for a particular language extension, perhaps consider opening a feature request on the repository in question.

Comment: Thanks, it works great on JS! Now I need to find a way to make it work with PHP.

Comment: That has to be handled by the language extension. Perhaps you open a feature request on the PHP extension / check if they would accept a pull request with this feature.

Comment: This does not work with Flutter as well after toggling the option mentioned above! Every time I have to add the brackets manually :D

- SG

Comment: Works for python too!

Answer (score 8):

Just like @snr's solution in JavaScript.

For TypeScript, you can try this:

`"typescript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true`

Comment: nice !  tried javascript but I had to use the typescript one. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

in settings.json file
Set `"python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true`.

[image: set "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true]

Comment: Please consider including the code itself rather than (just) a screenshot, as the former is more accessible and allows text searching and copying.

Comment: I am using Pylance and found I did not need ```"python.autocomplete.addBrackets": true``` but what did work for me was ```"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true```

Answer (score 5):

For Python, when using Pylance, add in settings.json:

```
"[python]": {
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
},
```

Answer (score 4):

You can go-to `File->Preferences->Settings`
Input `python`[image]

And click on `Edit in settings.json`
After that write down `"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,` and reload VS Code

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can create your own snippets, and it will be shown in the intellisense:
[User Defined snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets). You can also use [snippet-creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nikitaKunevich.snippet-creator) extension for comfort.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in flutter, try resetting all settings of VS Code because it do add parentheses by default.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest release of vs code open setting > search "parenthesis" > scroll for

python>analysis: Complete Function Parens

mark tick
Then you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no general setting that applies to all languages. VS Code [leaves this to individual language services to implement](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1021#issuecomment-171893794) (which is actually very reasonable given its extensibility model).

- For JavaScript, use `"javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true`. This will cause functions to be completed with their parameter signature.
- Analogously, for TypeScript, use `"typescript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true`.
- For [the PHP Intelephense extension](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense), the default value of the `intelephense.completion.triggerParameterHints` setting is `true`.
- For [the Python extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python), use `"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true`.
- For C and C++ using the [vscode-cpptools](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools) extension, use `"C_Cpp.autocompleteAddParentheses": true`.
- For [the Rust Analyzer extension](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/blob/master/editors/code), use `rust-analyzer.completion.callable.snippets` setting with either the value `"fill_arguments"`, or `"add_parenthesis"`. `"fill_arguments"` adds parenthesis *and* pre-fills arguments.
- I did a cursory search through [the Java extension](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java)'s settings and didn't find anything that looked related (maybe I just missed it). I also tried googling for feature-request issue tickets ("`github vscode java issues autocomplete function parenthesis`") and didn't find anything from a cursory look through the top search results.
- For C#, see [Method intellisense does not add parentheses
  #1453](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1453), which is closed to defer to the Roslyn issue [IDE: Intellisense: Insert full method call
  #12363](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12363)
- [The Dart extension](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code.git) just does this by default. See the `dart.completeFunctionCalls` setting, described as: "*Whether to insert parentheses and placeholders for positional and required arguments during code completions when using LSP. This feature is automatically disabled if commit characters are enabled.*".

Loosely related: this (fairly outdated and closed) VS Code issue ticket: [Autocomplete should insert parenthesis for methods
#1021](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1021).

There are some extensions I'm not sure about their behaviour (and am too lazy to try out right now): [R](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/blob/master/package.json), [Go](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/package.json), etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of VS Code, there is no UI element we can check/uncheck to enable this feature for javascript or typescript but as another Stackoverflow solution suggests, you need to edit the settings.json file in your system and add the following lines to your JSON object

1. F1 or 'Ctrl + Shift + P' to bring the command palette.
2. Select Settings.json for user settings.
3. Paste the following to the end of the file and save.

```js
"typescript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
"javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
```

Originally posted at:
[VSCode autocomplete function *and method* parentheses (js/ts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676976/vscode-autocomplete-function-and-method-parentheses-js-ts)

Comment: for python add line "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true