# How to add Auto Brackets in Visual studio Code like in JetBrains IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, jetbrains-ide, brackets

Using PyCharm, I would just type `print` and it would automatically add brackets once I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Is there an extension to this in VS Code?

So I would just have to type the name of, for example, a function I defined and while calling it, I would just type `functionName` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (return) and it would display: `functionName()`

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60472880/836330

Comment: And what language(s) do you want this for?

Comment: I want it mainly for Python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `Python`, with the `Python` extension from MS,

try `settings` -> `Python` -> `Auto complete: Add Brackets`
[image]

For `javascript` or `typescript`,

try `settings` -> `javascript`/`typescript` -> `Suggest: Complete Function Calls`

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Try Pasting this in settings.json:

```
"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this feature is not available in VS code by default. You will have to look for an extension. I'm sorry to say but after extensive research, I was not able to find any suitable extension

Answer (score 1):

Search **python > analysis** , scroll down to **complete function parens** and check that box.