# How to add Auto Brackets to function call in Visual studio Code like in JetBrains rider?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, rider

I recntly used jetbrains rider, and when I called a function there or used the auto complete option it automatically added bracket and semicolon.

is there is a way to do that also in VScode?

[How to add Auto Brackets in Visual studio Code like in JetBrains IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63965163/how-to-add-auto-brackets-in-visual-studio-code-like-in-jetbrains-ide)
I also saw this question but the answer only refered to python, js and typescript so is there is something like that to c#?