# How to stop VSCode AutoComplete arguments for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Whenever I type a widget name in VSCode, It automatically fills the argument of widgets. So, I have to manually change or delete the unnecessary arguments.
I have shown an example of a 'Text' widget . In the example the Text widget automatically enter 'data'.

[image]

I want to stop the autofilling of widget's arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for anyone else out there running into this, I found that setting `dart.completeFunctionCalls` to `false` worked for me.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75933450/11107541

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is available for non-ommittable parameters. But try to set parameter `dart.insertArgumentPlaceholders` to `false` in VS Code `settings.json` file.

Comment: I already set it to false. But nothing happens.