# VSCode autocomplete function *and method* parentheses (js/ts)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, methods, autocomplete

This is a superset of [VSCode add parentheses when automcompleting functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533379/vscode-add-parentheses-when-automcompleting-functions)

There is a setting in VSCode `javascript: complete function calls` that automatically adds in the parentheses and signature when you accept the autocomplete suggestion for a javascript function.  (The equivalent setting exists for Typescript.)

For example, if you have the function `function test(a,b) {return a+b;},` and you type `tes` and accept the suggestion, you'll get the full `test(a,b)` completed, not just `test`.

However (see gif at bottom for demos),

1. it appears not to work in `<script>` tags
2. it appears not to work for methods, e.g. `document.getElementById()`
3. it appears not to work for built-ins, like `new Date()`

thus restricting its usefulness.

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a way to extend the autocomplete functionality to include these scenarios.

I've opened a Github issue, in case this is a bug, but it's also possible I'm just misunderstand something.  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119035

Finally, here's a gif to demo the cases above: https://gfycat.com/carefulvibrantblackbuck

This is all running latest VSCode with no extensions.

Answer (score 8):

** 'Ctrl + Shift + P' => Settings.json:**

```
"typescript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
"javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
```

Comment: This does not work for functions I created in Javascript is there a way to make it work on that as well?

Comment: does not work for ts either