# Visual Studio Code Shortcut to "jump" a parentheses

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, shortcut

Is there any shortcut or extension to "jump" a parentheses?

Like pressing tab in PyCharm.

Comment: What do you mean "jump"?

Answer (score 1):

When you write a pair of parenthesis and if you don't want to press the right arrow, you can press the right paranthesis key and it will do the same thing. If you navigate inside the paranthesesis again, a closed paranthesis will be typed instead

Comment: It's unclear what the OP means by ""jump a parentheses".  I assumed "find the matching parenthesis", and I also assumed this is what PyCharm does.  But perhaps he/she meant "insert a matching parenthesis".  Hence your response.  +1.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [pdf](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) of shortcuts for VS Code

This other SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533379/vscode-add-parentheses-when-autocompleting-functions) may also have the answer you're looking for

I am assuming you are referring to autocompletion in VS code for C++

The shortcut you are looking for looks to be as shown in the PDF linked:

Mac: `CMD` + `SHIFT` + `\`

Windows: `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `\`

Comment: This is a link-only answer. They are useless to anyone who cannot visit the link for any number of reasons and become useless to everyone when the link rots.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid response: +1: 1) I take umbrage to the assumption "when the link rots".  I'd prefer *"if*".  2) Q: Do we *REALLY* want to copy/paste all the shortcuts in the entire .pdf?  Also consider: 3) Who's going to update the SO response if the information becomes obsolete?

Comment: @paulsm4 I see your point and should have expanded the comment with the fix: Summarize the relevant information from the link, the hot key or combination that performs the action desired by the asker, in the answer.

Comment: I see your point, I edited my response to show the specific commands associated in the linked VS Code PDF document.