# How to add parantheses when a function is autocompleted in Java and C# in VS Code

Tags: java, c#, function, visual-studio-code, brackets

I need to add parantheses when a function is autocompleted by Tab in Java and C# in VS Code, but I could not find the required settings for that. We can do the settings I said above for Python, JavaScript, C, C++. Is this possible for Java and C# ?

I took a look at this topic:
[VSCode add parentheses when autocompleting functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533379/vscode-add-parentheses-when-autocompleting-functions)

but I couldn't find the settings for Java and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the full **[Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)** extension package. One of the **[Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java)** extensions already contains this functionality.

[image]