# VSCode: disable parentheses when autocompleting functions in R

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

When a function is autocompleted it always adds brackets at the end. as an example, I want to use `mean`: I type `mea` > VSCode offers `mean` > I hit tab > I get `mean()`. But what I want to get is `mean`.

ideally I would be able to hit different shortcuts that would let me pick the options (with brackets, opening bracket only, no brackets), but I would also be happy with just disabling the `()` entirely.

This question has settings for how to do this in python, but I haven't been able to find a way to do this in R (or as a global setting that applies to all languages)
[VSCode add parentheses when autocompleting functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533379/vscode-add-parentheses-when-autocompleting-functions)

Note: I know about the editor 'auto closing brackets' setting, but this only works when I am doing the typing, not for auto complete.