# Disable parameter selection after completing "sout" in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

After I write
`sout`
and use auto completion for it to be `System.out.println();`

It shows this 
[image]

and I want to disable it..
Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

I tried many configurations related to `editor.suggest` in `vscode settings.json` but couldn't find the correct one.

Comment: loosely related (not an answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/75933450/11107541

Comment: May be `parameter hints` , disable the setting with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `java.signatureHelp.enabled` in the **Settings** panel and uncheck it.

[image]

Or add the following configuration in *settings.json*:

```json
    "java.signatureHelp.enabled": false,
```