# How do I set vs code to not add parentheses to autocomplete methods？

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes, adding parentheses automatically can be very annoying, so what can I do to turn this setting off?

[image: brackets]

I tried to search a lot of articles, but I didn't get an answer, and I was confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make VS Code add parentheses when autocompleting functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533379/how-can-i-make-vs-code-add-parentheses-when-autocompleting-functions) (the opposite question, but I think you'll find the answer to your question there just fine). If you scroll down a lot, you'll find an answer post of mine which I think is pretty decent.

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Although I personally think this feature is very useful, you can turn it off from here.

File > Preferences > Settings > Text Editor > Auto Closing Brackets > never

[image: Auto Closing Bracket]

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks

Comment: @sunny You're welcome, you should [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/819972) the answer for it to appear in the search results